# I'm getting "undefined method `hostname' for nil:NilClass1` when trying to do a relation in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do you get relationships working on rails? When I view an event from the `event` table in my database, I would like for the `sid` portion to show up as the hostname, and not the `sid`. When I change my `@event.sid` to `@event.ips_sensor.hostname` I get a "undefined method `hostname' for nil:NilClass1`.

Am I missing something in my `class IpsSensor` or `class IpsEvent`?

The Table in the db;

```
 sid | cid | signature |         timestamp          
-----+-----+-----------+----------------------------
   1 |   1 |         1 | 2014-05-22 20:50:07.154-04
```

My working View;

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Timestamp</th>
    <th>Sensor Name</th>
    <th>Signature</th>
    <th>Signature Class</th>
  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='timestamp'><%= @event.timestamp %></td>
        <td class='sensor_name'><%= @event.sid %></td>
        <td class='sig'><%= @event.signature %></td>
        <td class='sig_class'><%= @event.cid %></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

My attempt to do a relation;

```
undefined method `hostname' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #98):

95:       </tr>
96:           <tr>
97:             <td class='timestamp'><%= @event.timestamp %></td>
98:             <td class='sensor_name'><%= @event.ips_sensor.hostname %></td>
99:             <td class='sig'><%= @event.signature %></td>
100:             <td class='sig_class'><%= @event.cid %></td>
101:           </tr>
```

My Controller;

```
class IpsDashboardController < ApplicationController

  def ips_dashboard

    @event = IpsEvent.find(3)

  end
end
```

My event table aka `class IpsEvent`;

```
class IpsEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sid, :cid, :signature, :timestamp
  self.table_name = 'event'
  belongs_to :ips_sensor
end
```

My sensor table aka `class IpsSensor`;

```
class IpsSensor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sid, :hostname, :interface
  self.table_name = 'sensor'
  has_many :ips_events
end
```

What I would like to show up

```
SELECT hostname from sensor where sid = '1' ;

 hostname     
------------------
 VS-101:dna0:dna1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this, in your application helper define this method

```
def get_hostname(sid)
  IpsSensor.where("sid =?", sid).first.hostname
end
```

In your view

```
<td class='sensor_name'><%= get_hostname(@event.sid) %></td>
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but I get an undefined method `hostname`. Am I missing something in my `class IpsSensor` that would define the hostname method other than `attr_accessible :sid, :hostname, :interface`, and `attr_accessor :sid, :hostname, :interface`

Comment: Well I think you have got me closer, but it's just coming back blank now. But no undefined method error.

Comment: Hostname might be blank in the table

Comment: That worked for sid and hostname. Thanks much!! When I try to do the same for `@event.signature` I'm getting an invalid statement, but I'll keep plugging away at it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> How do you get relationships working on rails?

[Rails associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) are just methods which populate methods with data in associative tables. You'll generally need to use a `foreign_key` to associate the data, but after that, you'll be able to access the data as required like so:

```
#app/models/model_1.rb
Class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :model2
end

#app/models/model_2.rb
Class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :model1
end

#-> @model1.model2
```

---

**Foreign Keys**

```
nil:NilClass1
```

When you get this error, it typically means your `parent` variable is not being populated:

```
@event.ips_sensor.hostname #-> means @event or ips_sensor won't be populated
```

The problem I can see is when you're trying to access your `ips_sensor` association, you're firstly using `attr_accessible` (are you using Rails 3 or 4?)

--

I would do this:

```
#app/models/ips_event.rb
class IpsEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :ips_sensor
   #-> schema: id | ips_sensor_id | other | details | created_at | updated_at
   #-> if you want to use other foreign_keys, set with the foreign_key: "column" argument for the association
end

#app/models/ips_sensor.rb
Class IpsSensor < Activerecord::Base
   has_many :ips_events
end
```

-

```
#app/controllers/ips_dashboard_controller.rb
def ips_dashboard
    @event = IpsEvent.find 3
end
```

-

```
#app/views/ips_dashboards/ips_dashboard.html.erb
<%= @event.ips_sensor.hostname #-> considering ips_sensor has the hostname attribute %>
```

Comment: In that case, what I have recommended should work except you need to add `attr_accessible`